# Need an explanation of this javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I have a question about this script I found and used. It works but I don't get why. The exercise was to make a list with random numbers from -50 to 50. The function below uses `Math.floor(Math.random() *` (the part i dont understand).

If I put this calculation on google I got as answer 151 and `Math.random()*151` does not do from -50 to 50.

Can someone give me a clear explanation about this function below because I am sure that I am missing something.

**this script works but I only want a clear explanation how**

```
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    Rnumber[i] = randomFromTo(-50,50);
}

function randomFromTo(from, to)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}
```

Comment: thank you bobbymcr for correcting my bad English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
to - from + 1 = 50 - (-50) + 1 = 101
Math.random() * 101 = number in range [0,101[
Math.floor([0,101[) = integer in range [0,100]
[0,100] + from = [0,100] + (-50) = integer in range [-50,50]
```

Which is exactly what is asked for.

Comment: Quick question: Does Math.random() ever return 1.0?  And if so, wouldn't that mean it's possible for "51" to be returned from the OP's randomFromTo function?

Comment: No, it dosn't. It never includes 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

> Math.random returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the
>   range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1
>   (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range.

which when multiplied with a number > 1 and floored gives you an integer

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()`  - get only value between 0 and 1.
`Math.floor( number )` get integer down rounded value from number.
You should:

```
function randomFromTo(from, to)
{
  // you can use doubled bitwise NOT operator which also as Math.floor get integer value from number but is much faster.
  // ~1 == -2 , ~-2 == 1 and   ~1.5 == -2 :)

 return  ~~( --from + ( Math.random() * ( ++to - from )) )
}
```